# Ideal Chi-squared for X-ray pattern Le Bail fit

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction

I have made a potentially novel solid state phase. I know the general parameters it should have, and have been trying to Le Bail fit XRD data about this phase prior to a synchrotron run in May. I have achieved a chi-square of 11.1 using a Bruker D2 Phaser and FullProf refinement software.

Does this mean I have my compound, but perhaps there are small impurities? Or does it mean that the fit is worthless? I'm afraid I do not know what the "non-ideal but still ok" range of fit is.

Comment: First off, what is this mystery matetial?

Comment: (If I am correct), it is a monoclinic Wadsley-Roth phase. The lattice parameters and space groups of these materials can be easily predicted as a function of the stoichiometry and oxygen deficiency. When using these predicted parameters, I get a relatively decent looking fit, but it has a chisquare of 11.1. It is very possible that there are small impurities in here, one of the precursors is very expensive to acquire better than 99% purity of, so I want to make sure the phase is correct before buying the more expensive precursor. I just don't know if 11.1 means "fit is wrong" or "impurities".